# Declaration class as array in AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I wanted to declare a variable like this in AX 2012 :
classX[] error = new classX(); in a Class Y

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public classX
{

}

[DataContractAttribute]
public classY
{
      classX[]  error = new classX();
}
```

But I can't declare it, is that possible?

I tried it this way but it didn't work:
Array error = Array of classX;
classX error[] = new classX();

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do what you're trying to accomplish is below. [Take a look at this link for some more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/using-custom-services).

## ClassY definition:

```
[DataContractAttribute]
class ClassYContract
{
    List classXList;
}

[
    DataMemberAttribute,
    AifCollectionTypeAttribute('return', Types::Class, classStr(ClassXContract)),
    AifCollectionTypeAttribute('_classXList', Types::Class, classStr(ClassXContract))
]
public List parmClassXList(List _classXList = classXList)
{
    classXList = _classXList;

    return classXList;
}
```

## ClassX definition:

```
[DataContractAttribute]
class ClassXContract
{
}
```

Comment: I will like to add, even if syntactically legal, in old AX versions it crashed the client (or server), maybe because the garbage collector did not understand arrays of objects!
I have not tested in D365FO, but maybe they changed the compiler to bark instead.